# command line arguments into make file

Tags: c, makefile, command-line-arguments

I have a C file for which I want to give cmd line arguments.

Say

```
$ make --argument1
```

or something like this.

So that in my main program I should be able to do argv[1] and be able to access the variable.

I have tried looking for  ways of doing this. Is there actually a way of doing this?

These were the relevant content I found on the GNULinux manual about make.

> variables defined on the command line are passed to the sub-make
>   through MAKEFLAGS. Words in the value of MAKEFLAGS that contain ‘=’,
>   make treats as variable definitions just as if they appeared on the
>   command line.

Is this what I need to read up more or is this in a different context?

Do let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the use of command line arguments - they are given when the executable is executed not when it is compiled.

Better example

foo.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int myval=DEFVAL;

   printf("myval=%d\n", myval);
   return 0;
}
```

Makefile

```
DEFVAL=17

foo: foo.c
   gcc -DDEFVAL=${DEFVAL} foo.c -o $@
```

Comment: Oh I see. The thing is the executable generated is not directly run on the terminal. Its an arm .axf file which is run on an emulator. So I wanted to know if there is a way of letting the user specify what the value of a certain variable has to be

Comment: You could use the #define method I describe or ask the user for the value.

Comment: @user1357576  The use of "user" and "make" in the discussion doesn't seem right. Do your users have the capability to build the program before they run it? If not, you should look into using the argc and argv[] parameters to main.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make a whole lot of sense, so I'm going to read between the lines and guess that you have a Makefile that someone else wrote, and when you run make, it runs some program, and that's the program that you want to give command line arguments.

In order to do that, you'll probably have to modify the Makefile.  In order to that, it helps to understand how make works and how to use it (you might want to find a book on the subject, such as [this one](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780937175903.do)), but it may possible to modify the Makefile without too much trouble.

Somewhere in the Makefile, you'll find the action line that is used to invoke you're program.  If you can find that line, you can add the argument you want.